# Pull to refresh (ChrisBanes) - save and restore position after refresh

Tags: android, listview, position

I'm using the amazing library pull-to-refresh of Chris Banes.

Everything works. But the listview does not have methods
onSaveInstanceState
onRestoreInstanceState

Therefore, I do not know how to go to the new position of loaded elements.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have seen in the code of the class that Chris has provided the method:

getRefreshableView

Which gives access to the object within the envelope.

Its works! ;)